# Spring SQSListener for remote queue

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Is it possible to use SQS from a AWS different account to listen to using the following ?

```
    public void consume(
        UpdateMessage message,
        @Header(SqsHeaders.MessageSystemAttributes.SQS_SENDER_ID) String senderId
    ) {

Could someone please let me know?
```